# app rejected by app store for non consumable product

Tags: iphone, in-app-purchase, appstore-approval

We found that while your app offers In-App Purchase(s) that can be restored, it does not include the required "Restore" feature to allow users to restore the previously purchased In-App Purchase(s), as specified in Restoring Transactions section of the In-App Purchase Programming Guide:

"...if your application supports product types that must be restorable, you must include an interface that allows users to restore these purchases. This interface allows a user to add the product to other devices or, if the original device was wiped, to restore the transaction on the original device."

To restore previously purchased In-App Purchase products, it would be appropriate to provide a "Restore" button and initiate the restore process when the "Restore" button is tapped by the user.

For more information about restoring transactions and verifying store receipt, please refer to the In-App Purchase Programming Guide.

I have used these restore methods:

```
- (void) restoreTransaction: (SKPaymentTransaction *)transaction {
    [self recordTransaction: transaction]; 
    [self provideContent: transaction.originalTransaction.payment.productIdentifier];
    [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] finishTransaction: transaction]; 
}

- (void)paymentQueue:(SKPaymentQueue *)queue restoreCompletedTransactionsFailedWithError:(NSError *)error;
```

Please any one tell me what is missing in my interface?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you actually have a "Restore" button to call these methods?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add a **Restore Purchases** button, meaning you need to give the user a way to restore the items they have purchased.

Comment: thanks for your reply, i have create a restore button on the UI and call restoreCompletedTransactions method on the button action, i have also implement paymentQueueRestoreCompletedTransactionsFinished delegate method. please suggest me it is enough for this because in sandbox testing any delegate method not called in my end.

Comment: Yes, as long as the (paid for) purchases restore properly this is all you need to do to resubmit the app for approval.